# MVC Razor, accept less then sign (<) in text input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am new to MVC Razor, I am facing problem to accept less then character(<) from input text on form post. Its a simple form has only one text input within `Html.BeginForm()`. When user inputs < sign in input text, razor view crashes on form post.

Please help.

Comment: Use [AllowHtml] attribute  for that field. or [ValidateInput(false)] in the controller function but it's better to use  [AllowHtml] attribute in the model.

Comment: @Rakib you are rock, it's working :)

Comment: @Rakib: Please post that as an answer so the OP can accept it. Otherwise, this question remains "unanswered" forever.

Comment: @Adil please marked it as a approved answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AllowHtml] attribute for that field. or [ValidateInput(false)] in the controller function but it's better to use [AllowHtml] attribute in the model